# How Can I Add, and Use, a Color Scheme for Geany?

Tags: customization, programming, geany

I have found that one of my favorite text editors for programming is Geany, however the default color scheme is very bright and hurts my eyes when programming for awhile. There are other color schemes available for Geany but no clear way for installing and using them. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: "*There are other color schemes available..*" where? I couldn't find any related option on the program. What version of Geany do you have?

Comment: Im not sure about the version but the "other" schemes are available under view>editor>color schemes...

Comment: You can invert the scheme: Edit > Preferences > Editor > Display > Invert highlighter color scheme.

Comment: For those who did not find it under `View → Change Color Scheme` check under `View → Editor → Change Color Scheme`.
I wanted to add this as a comment but don't have the rep enough, sorry.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- You can invert the scheme:

  Edit → Preferences → Editor → Display → Check: Invert highlighter color scheme.
- The alt scheme is in (You may test if can add other one or just modify this one)

  ```
  /usr/share/geany/colorschemes/alt.conf
  ```

  **Note:** How did I found this?

  I check for geany packages using `synaptic`. Looking in their *Installed Files* tab then it was found in `geany-common` package.

Comment: What worked for me was adding the files to `~/.config/geany/` and then adding the proper items to the filedefs and colorschemes folders. I might also note that I am using version 0.21 in Ubuntu; may vary between distros.

Comment: Invert syntax highlighting colors in version 1.32. Click Apply and it turns from white to black.

Comment: It should be noted that inverting the color scheme breaks custom themes to some degree.

Answer (score 53):

You can get theme files from https://github.com/codebrainz/geany-themes (I prefer *Spyder Dark* and *InkPot*). The easiest way is to click "Clone or download" and then "Download ZIP".

Just copy the `.conf` files directly into `~/.config/geany/colorschemes/`. (Not wrapped in another subfolder as a result of downloading, archive extraction or Git.)

They will immediately be available from the menu bar under `View → Change Color Scheme...`

**Note:** These work for Geany 1.22 and above. For older versions you may need to:

- download different files (links provided in the README above or at http://wiki.geany.org/themes/start)
- navigate to `View → Editor → Change Color Scheme` instead
- restart Geany before the themes appear as new options

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: I like most oblivion2, btw we could list here all the dark ones :)

Comment: Sad how little of the UI is themed :(

Comment: For newer versions of Geany (1.22 and above), this is the best answer (in my opinion).

Answer (score 5):

You may try this solution to change the color scheme of your Geany Text Editor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3flgO81_3dE.

Download Geany Color Scheme from here: https://github.com/geany/geany-themes/

Comment: +1 for the link to the original geany repo.

Answer (score 4):

Even as this thread is quite old, I think I can provide a simpler solution to change Geany to a dark theme if you don't mind change your theme to dark system-wide. Actually it has to done in two steps:

1. Change the style of the editor window, in order to do so, just follow the instructions in [Geany Darkthemes](https://www.geany.org/download/themes/)
2. Change the system theme to dark. At least in Ubuntu you might do that in the *Settings Manager*, for XUbuntu, I follow the instructions here: [XUbuntu 20.04 Release Notes](https://wiki.xubuntu.org/releases/20.04/release-notes) (at the Greybird Dark Theme), note that you have to change both the *Appearance* and the *Window Manager*. I suppose that in other distribution there will be similar tools to change to dark theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the github page from  https://github.com/codebrainz/geany-themes.
then what you do is extract that file somewhere, then run the install.sh file located directly inside the geany-themes file and it will put all the new themes in the correct place for you.